# Autodesk Forge API for Cloud Credit Consumption Summary

Tags: autodesk-forge

I had been working with AutodeskForge API and I want to know if Autodesk Forge has a service to know the consumption of credits that there is some extent. The main idea is try to limit the use of some elements in case of exceeding a certain use of credits and having an API that provides this information would be of great help.

I appreciate any help or suggestions regarding this matter.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no such API to provide the Forge consumption, we do have Token Flex API at https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/tokenflex/v1/developers_guide/overview/, but this seems not the API what you are looking for.

Comment: No, I checked the Token Flex API but as you comment, it is not what I was looking for. Thanks for your answer.